# C++ using time as an array

Tags: c++, if-statement, time

Hi guys need you guys help again. May i ask how do i make a array with time.
My first source file is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(void)
{
extern int timeLeavingTP[];
extern int transitTime27[];
extern int transitTime8 [];
extern int transitTime15[];
extern int transitTime23[];
extern int busStopTime[];
int transitNumber;
printf("Please enter the time leaving TP in 24 hour format.\n");
scanf_s("%d",&timeLeavingTP);
printf("Please enter bus number.\n");
scanf_s("%d",&transitNumber);
if(timeLeavingTP[0])
{

    if(transitNumber==27)
    {
    printf("The predicted time reached home is %d.\n",(transitTime27[0]+timeLeavingTP[0]+busStopTime[0]));
    }
    if(transitNumber==8)
    {
    printf("The predicted time reached home is %d.\n",(transitTime8[0]+timeLeavingTP[0]+busStopTime[0]));
    }
    if(transitNumber==15)
    {
    printf("The predicted time reached home is %d.\n",(transitTime15[0]+timeLeavingTP[0]+busStopTime[0]));
    }
    if(transitNumber==23)
    {
    printf("The predicted time reached home is %d.\n",(transitTime23[0]+timeLeavingTP[0]+busStopTime[0]));
    }
_putch('\n');
puts("\n\tPress any key to continue ...");
_putch('\t');
_getch();;
}
```

My second source file is:

```
int transitTime[4][12];
int transitTime27[]={56,58,57,52,54,53,31,49,51,57,62,65};
int transitTime8 []={39,43,40,34,37,36,31,32,42,49,59,61};
int transitTime15[]={42,47,43,42,51,49,40,41,48,50,58,62};
int transitTime23[]={50,55,51,49,52,47,49,48,53,41,55,63};

int timeLeavingTP[]={1300,1330,1400,1430,1500,1530,1600,1630,1700,1730,1800,1830};

int busStopTime[]={9,9,9,17,17,18,16,12,10,8,8,8};
```

When i debug the the program i got the time for example 1665 instead of 1705. May i ask how to change it? Thanks guys!!

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect otherwise. Consider storing the time as minutes since 00:00 instead of making it look nice

Comment: And if you have a constant like `unsigned const HOURS = 60`, you could do `15 * HOURS + 30` readability

Comment: or a macro like `TIME(H, M) H*60+M` to get `TIME(15, 30)`

Comment: What do the numbers in your `transitTime` arrays represent?

Comment: What numbers did you input to get your result of 1665 or 1705?

Comment: You are missing a 3rd input variable, which I think should be used as an index into the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `transitTime` arrays are not consecutive in name, I'll assume they won't be inside an array of `transitTime`.

My suggestion is to have a container of index structures:

```
struct Time_Table_Entry
{
  unsigned int    transit_number;
  unsigned int    times[12];
};

const Time_Table_Entry time_table[] =
{
  {
    8, // Transit number
    {39,43,40,34,37,36,31,32,42,49,59,61}
  },
  {
    27,
    {56,58,57,52,54,53,31,49,51,57,62,65}
  },
  //...
};
const unsigned int time_table_entries =
    sizeof(time_table) / sizeof(time_table[0]);
```